# Rearrange table in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a table of water quality data. Currently it looks like this, except the last three columns are populated with data:

[image]

But I'd like to change it into this format:

[image]

#### Example Dataframe

```
structure(list(season = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("Winter", 
"Spring", "Summer", "Autumn"), class = "factor"), site = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"), 
    Temp = c("7.2(1.56)", "7.05(1.91)", "6.3(1.7)", "6.25(2.33)", 
    "6.2(2.4)", "5.4(2.4)", "11.77(2.75)", "12.5(4.62)", "11.6(3.68)", 
    "11.13(3.81)", "11(3.67)", "13.57(4.15)", "13(1.51)", "15.13(1.65)", 
    "14.4(0.75)", "14.93(1.19)", "14.97(1.29)", "21(3.24)"), 
    pH = c("7.44(0.29)", "7.38(0.28)", "7.52(0.1)", "7.53(0.12)", 
    "7.38(0.06)", "7.56(0.26)", "7.21(0.1)", "7.2(0.13)", "7.35(0.08)", 
    "7.44(0.06)", "7.46(0.02)", "7.72(0.11)", "7.35(0.1)", "7.48(0.12)", 
    "7.44(0.05)", "7.12(0.14)", "7.15(0.03)", "7.86(0.38)"), 
    `DO` = c("9(0)", "9.1(0.42)", "8.25(0.07)", 
    "8.85(0.49)", "9.25(0.64)", "9(0.42)", "8.73(1.32)", "8.13(2.85)", 
    "7.37(1.16)", "8.3(1.5)", "8.47(1.21)", "9.2(0.79)", "7.43(1.21)", 
    "5.63(3.33)", "7.07(1.12)", "4.77(2.5)", "5(1.1)", "7.87(1.07)"
    ), `EC` = c("337.5(55.86)", "333(41.01)", 
    "321.5(51.62)", "322(32.53)", "309(25.46)", "300.5(30.41)", 
    "407.67(13.58)", "404(12.29)", "376.33(8.08)", "337.33(8.5)", 
    "333.67(13.5)", "290.67(9.24)", "474(7.21)", "464.33(8.33)", 
    "409(4.36)", "389.33(30.27)", "368.67(19.6)", "327.67(18.58)"
    )), row.names = c(NA, 18L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update on OP request:**
**version1:**

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(season,site)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = season, values_from = value) %>% 
  arrange(name, site) %>% 
  relocate(name, site) %>% 
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels =  colnames(df[-c(1:2)]))) %>% 
  arrange(name) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(name = ifelse(row_number()==1, as.character(name), "")) %>% 
  print(n=30)
```

```
 name   site  Winter       Spring        Summer       
   <chr>  <fct> <chr>        <chr>         <chr>        
 1 "Temp" 1     7.2(1.56)    11.77(2.75)   13(1.51)     
 2 ""     2     7.05(1.91)   12.5(4.62)    15.13(1.65)  
 3 ""     3     6.3(1.7)     11.6(3.68)    14.4(0.75)   
 4 ""     4     6.25(2.33)   11.13(3.81)   14.93(1.19)  
 5 ""     5     6.2(2.4)     11(3.67)      14.97(1.29)  
 6 ""     6     5.4(2.4)     13.57(4.15)   21(3.24)     
 7 "pH"   1     7.44(0.29)   7.21(0.1)     7.35(0.1)    
 8 ""     2     7.38(0.28)   7.2(0.13)     7.48(0.12)   
 9 ""     3     7.52(0.1)    7.35(0.08)    7.44(0.05)   
10 ""     4     7.53(0.12)   7.44(0.06)    7.12(0.14)   
11 ""     5     7.38(0.06)   7.46(0.02)    7.15(0.03)   
12 ""     6     7.56(0.26)   7.72(0.11)    7.86(0.38)   
13 "DO"   1     9(0)         8.73(1.32)    7.43(1.21)   
14 ""     2     9.1(0.42)    8.13(2.85)    5.63(3.33)   
15 ""     3     8.25(0.07)   7.37(1.16)    7.07(1.12)   
16 ""     4     8.85(0.49)   8.3(1.5)      4.77(2.5)    
17 ""     5     9.25(0.64)   8.47(1.21)    5(1.1)       
18 ""     6     9(0.42)      9.2(0.79)     7.87(1.07)   
19 "EC"   1     337.5(55.86) 407.67(13.58) 474(7.21)    
20 ""     2     333(41.01)   404(12.29)    464.33(8.33) 
21 ""     3     321.5(51.62) 376.33(8.08)  409(4.36)    
22 ""     4     322(32.53)   337.33(8.5)   389.33(30.27)
23 ""     5     309(25.46)   333.67(13.5)  368.67(19.6) 
24 ""     6     300.5(30.41) 290.67(9.24)  327.67(18.58)
```

**version2:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(season,site)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = season, values_from = value) %>% 
  arrange(name, site) %>% 
  relocate(name, site) %>% 
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels =  colnames(df[-c(1:2)]))) %>% 
  arrange(name) %>% 
  print(n=30)
```

```
 name  site  Winter       Spring        Summer       
   <fct> <fct> <chr>        <chr>         <chr>        
 1 Temp  1     7.2(1.56)    11.77(2.75)   13(1.51)     
 2 Temp  2     7.05(1.91)   12.5(4.62)    15.13(1.65)  
 3 Temp  3     6.3(1.7)     11.6(3.68)    14.4(0.75)   
 4 Temp  4     6.25(2.33)   11.13(3.81)   14.93(1.19)  
 5 Temp  5     6.2(2.4)     11(3.67)      14.97(1.29)  
 6 Temp  6     5.4(2.4)     13.57(4.15)   21(3.24)     
 7 pH    1     7.44(0.29)   7.21(0.1)     7.35(0.1)    
 8 pH    2     7.38(0.28)   7.2(0.13)     7.48(0.12)   
 9 pH    3     7.52(0.1)    7.35(0.08)    7.44(0.05)   
10 pH    4     7.53(0.12)   7.44(0.06)    7.12(0.14)   
11 pH    5     7.38(0.06)   7.46(0.02)    7.15(0.03)   
12 pH    6     7.56(0.26)   7.72(0.11)    7.86(0.38)   
13 DO    1     9(0)         8.73(1.32)    7.43(1.21)   
14 DO    2     9.1(0.42)    8.13(2.85)    5.63(3.33)   
15 DO    3     8.25(0.07)   7.37(1.16)    7.07(1.12)   
16 DO    4     8.85(0.49)   8.3(1.5)      4.77(2.5)    
17 DO    5     9.25(0.64)   8.47(1.21)    5(1.1)       
18 DO    6     9(0.42)      9.2(0.79)     7.87(1.07)   
19 EC    1     337.5(55.86) 407.67(13.58) 474(7.21)    
20 EC    2     333(41.01)   404(12.29)    464.33(8.33) 
21 EC    3     321.5(51.62) 376.33(8.08)  409(4.36)    
22 EC    4     322(32.53)   337.33(8.5)   389.33(30.27)
23 EC    5     309(25.46)   333.67(13.5)  368.67(19.6) 
24 EC    6     300.5(30.41) 290.67(9.24)  327.67(18.58)
```

**First answer:**
We could do it this way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(season,site)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = season, values_from = value) %>% 
  arrange(name, site) %>% 
  relocate(name, site)
```

```
# A tibble: 24 x 5
   name  site  Winter       Spring        Summer       
   <chr> <fct> <chr>        <chr>         <chr>        
 1 DO    1     9(0)         8.73(1.32)    7.43(1.21)   
 2 DO    2     9.1(0.42)    8.13(2.85)    5.63(3.33)   
 3 DO    3     8.25(0.07)   7.37(1.16)    7.07(1.12)   
 4 DO    4     8.85(0.49)   8.3(1.5)      4.77(2.5)    
 5 DO    5     9.25(0.64)   8.47(1.21)    5(1.1)       
 6 DO    6     9(0.42)      9.2(0.79)     7.87(1.07)   
 7 EC    1     337.5(55.86) 407.67(13.58) 474(7.21)    
 8 EC    2     333(41.01)   404(12.29)    464.33(8.33) 
 9 EC    3     321.5(51.62) 376.33(8.08)  409(4.36)    
10 EC    4     322(32.53)   337.33(8.5)   389.33(30.27)
# ... with 14 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: You could add `group_by(name) %>%   mutate(name = ifelse(row_number()==1, name, ""))` if you want.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the original order of columns, rather than alphabetically?

Comment: Yes please see my update. I will add the suggested code. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? Using `tidyr`

```
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(Temperature:`Dissolved Organic Carbon`)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = season, values_from = value)
```

Output

```
   site  name                        Winter      
   <fct> <chr>                       <chr>       
 1 1     Temperature                 7.2(1.56)   
 2 1     pH                          7.44(0.29)  
 3 1     Dissolved Oxygen            9(0)        
 4 1     Electrical Conductivity     337.5(55.86)
 5 1     Suspended Sediment          5.94(0.73)  
 6 1     Total Phosphorus            73.5(3.54)  
 7 1     Soluble Reactive Phosphorus 19(2.83)    
 8 1     Particulate Phosphorus      54.5(6.36)  
 9 1     Dissolved Ammonia           0.08(0)     
10 1     Dissolved Nitrite           0.05(0.03)
```